# Xampp - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = "INSERT INTO clients(ID_Client,Upgrade,Nome,Email,Cod_Postal,Localidade,Contacto,NIF,Factura,Data_Factura,N_Serie,Codigo,Marca,Modelo) VALUES (NULL,'$Upgrade',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Nome',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Email',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Cod_Postal',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Localidade',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Contacto',
                                                                                                                                                            '$NIF',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Factura',
                                                                                                                                                            '$N_Serie',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Data_Factura',                                                                                                                                                                ".$N_Serie.",
                                                                                                                                                            '$Codigo',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Marca',
                                                                                                                                                            '$Modelo')";
```

What it's wrong about this ? I got the same number of fields / values ..

Comment: For one, this would be a lot easier to understand with some sane code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You've got '$N_Serie', twice, remove the first one.

Columns matching values below:

```
$query = "
INSERT INTO clients(
    ID_Client,
    Upgrade,
    Nome,
    Email,
    Cod_Postal,
    Localidade,
    Contacto,
    NIF,
    Factura,
    Data_Factura,
    N_Serie,
    Codigo,
    Marca,
    Modelo
) VALUES (
    NULL,
    '$Upgrade',
    '$Nome',
    '$Email',
    '$Cod_Postal',
    '$Localidade',
    '$Contacto',
    '$NIF',
    '$Factura',
    '$Data_Factura',
    '$N_Serie',
    '$Codigo',
    '$Marca',
    '$Modelo'
)";
```